# Getting character count of EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get a character count of an EditText. I've looked into different properties of the EditText and TextView classes, but there doesn't seem to be a function that returns the amount of characters. I have tried to use the TextWatcher, but that is not ideal since sometimes I load a saved message into the EditText from the preferences, and TextWatcher does not count characters not typed right then.

Any help would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: I know its already have been answered. But It may help to others. You can also use editText.length()

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just grab the text in the EditText as a string and check its length:

```
int length = editText.getText().length();
```

Comment: Great, but how can we show that count TextView just right-below of the edittext and should be visible while user is typing. We know that there is no space to show anything between keypad and edittext. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

```
EditText edittext;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets a textview to the current length
           textview.setText(String.valueOf(s.length());
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
};
 editText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Comment: you can just get the EditText ang get it's text as String and get the length of that string.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin it's very easy

<EditText_name>.Text.length

Comment: 10 years ago when this was asked Kotlin didn't exist.

Comment: I just wanna contribute to the future. Might be helpful for someone else :)