# android display toast message if edittext of alert dialoge is null

Tags: android, null, android-alertdialog

android display toast message if edittext of alert dialog is null

I am trying to make a simple validation for edittext of alert dialog, in a way that if the user didn't enter his name on the edittext of alert dialog and pressed yes button a toast message should be displayed that says "please enter your name".

I made a code to make this validation but the problem after toast message displayed the alert dialog is closed and I want the alert dialog to still opened until the user enter his name.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            alert.setTitle("user info");
            alert.setMessage("enter your name");


           // Set an EditText view to get user input
            final EditText ed = new EditText(context);
            int maxLength = 10;
            ed.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(
                    maxLength) });
            alert.setView(ed);
            alert.setCancelable(false);



            alert.setPositiveButton("ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {



  if (ed.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    {   

 CharSequence error = "please enter your name";
 int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, error, duration);
 toast.show();

    }

else{
    startNextActivity(context);
    }


                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
        }
```

Comment: Show code for complete alert dialog.

Comment: @Nitesh I added the complete alert dialog code

Comment: You can look this question [Getting character count of EditText][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960981/getting-character-count-of-edittext

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (ed.getText().length() == 0) {
        ed.setError("please enter your name");
  } else {
        startNextActivity(context);
  }
```

Comment: I tried it but if I pressed ok button the alert dialog will go even if the user didn't enter his name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setView(v)
    .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) //Set to null. We override the onclick
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
    .create();

 d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

    Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ed.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
{   

   CharSequence error = "please enter your name";
   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, error, duration);
  toast.show();

}else
{
  d.dismiss();
}

        }
    });
}
 });
```

It will work for sure and mark as right if it does. :)

Comment: d refers to tha dialog.
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)

So if your condition is false or the user has entered some text into the edittext then it will close thedialogue.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You have to create and show the alert dialog and dismiss it when you need. So until then the dialog shows.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

alert.setTitle("user info");
alert.setMessage("enter your name");


final EditText ed = new EditText(context);
int maxLength = 10;
ed.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(
        maxLength) });
alert.setView(ed);
alert.setCancelable(false);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
dialog.show();

dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (ed.getText().toString().length() == 0 ){   

            CharSequence error = "please enter your name";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, error, duration);
            toast.show();

        }else{
          dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
});
```